# Trying to Automate React Native builds with Firebase App Distribution using Gitlab CI/CID in windows

Tags: react-native, gitlab-ci, cicd, firebase-app-distribution, gitlab-ci.yml

**I'm having trouble automating react native release build apps using firebase app distribution with Gitlab CI/CD.**  I get this error **Error: set the --app option to a valid Firebase app id and try again**
Also see image:[image: See image here]

*I've setup "**.gitlab-ci.yml**" file as below*

```
## install project deps with --frozen-lockfile to make sure we will have the same packages version ( very recommended  on running yarn install on ci)
##run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
before_script:
  - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
  - yarn global add firebase-tools

stages:
  - buildApp

buildApp project:
  stage: buildApp
  image: reactnativecommunity/react-native-android
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - yarn.lock
    paths:
      - node_modules
    policy: pull #`pull` the jobs pull the cache at the beginning but do not push the changes again.
  script:
    - yarn build:apk
    - yarn install --pure-lockfile --cache-folder .yarn
    - ./bin/app_distribution.sh
    # - firebase use kavyatara --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"
    # - firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN"

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

Also
**app_distribution.sh file**

#!/bin/bash
RELEASE_NOTE="New update Android build"

```
firebase appdistribution:distribute android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk   \
    --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" \
    --app "$FIREBASE_APP_ID" \
    --release-notes "$RELEASE_NOTE" --testers-file testers.txt
```

Comment: could you try to hardcode the firebase app id in you script app distribution script?

Comment: @alvAro365 okay trying with hardcode firebase app id in the script. Also do you know why I'm not getting cache result though I've cached node_modules ?